# This error occurs when I use fit_generate method for my CNN model - "Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL."

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
```

> Compile

```
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

> ERROR OCCURS WHEN I RUN THE BELOW LINE

```
**classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 8000,
epochs = 25,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 2000)**
```

[image: A snapshot of the error]

Comment: `pip install pil`?

Comment: Tried - Doesnt work...

Answer (score 0):

(For someone else's reference)
Found the solution : 
Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall Anaconda3 = 1.6.2. Then install Theano + TensorFlow and Keras using anaconda-prompt commands.